# Using a Search Bar through an sqlite database

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, sqlite, uisearchbar

I am building an iPhone application loading data from SQLite database. Until now I have managed to deal with it as it should, but now i need to add a search bar on top to search through the database content dynamically and obtain the proper search results.

I am using Xcode 4.3.3 , and I am a newb in Xcoding.

I have seen almost every tutorial ever posted online and i need some help.

Anyone have any very specific tutorial or sample code that could help? It will be highly appreciated.

Comment: which part is causing trouble, handling uisearchbar events or querying db?

Comment: actually passing the query to the search bar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everyone this is the most helpful link ever found

http://code-ninja.org/blog/2012/01/08/ios-quick-tip-filtering-a-uitableview-with-a-search-bar/

Answer (score 0):

You could use an NSPredicate.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"whatYouAreSearching LIKE %@", searchBar.text];
```

If you're using an NSFetchRequest, you can assign it a predicate using it's setPredicate method.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller must implement UISearchBarDelegate protocol

then in init method, add this or similar

```
CGRect searchBarRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44);
_searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:searchBarRect];
_searchBar.delegate = self;
```

after that, implement these three methods, I will post something that looks like mine implementations

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];
    self.tableView.allowsSelection = NO;
    self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    searchBar.text=@"";
    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    self.tableView.allowsSelection = YES;
    self.tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {

    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    self.tableView.allowsSelection = YES;
    self.tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;

    /* fire method that does querying with searchBar.text as attribute */
    [self some method:searchBar.text];
}
```

Comment: first of all thank you for your response, second , the method that does the querying, how can i actually create it...following several tutorial i am lost, how to do an automatic search and filtering data?